# How do I write a formula in excel that lets me evaluate if each value in a row is TRUE?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Basically, I want the most efficient way to do something like the following in the most efficient way possible and with a lot more columns:

```
=and(f2=true,g2=true,h2=true,i2=true)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this very concisely with an array formula. Paste the following into the formula bar and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=AND(F2:I2)
```

**EDIT:**
In response to Jerry's comment, if the range you are checking will contain anything other than boolean values, you'll need to use a more specific formula (because all text, blanks, and numbers not equal to 0 will evaluate as `TRUE`). The following will only consider cells with the boolean value `TRUE` as true.

```
=AND(F2:I2=TRUE)
```

This should also be entered as an array function by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If by chance you want to count both `TRUE` and `1` as true, you can use this more complicated array formula (entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

```
=AND(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(F2:I2,{TRUE,1},0))))
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Somehow, I was under the impression that all array formulae don't work in `AND()`. Turned out that's applicable only when there's more than one condition! +1 Still though, I prefer non-array formulae when possible.

Comment: @Jerry I know what you mean about `AND` not working in array formulas. It works as an aggregator (not sure if that's the proper term) like `SUM`, `MIN`, and `SUMPRODUCT`, i.e., it can take an array as an argument, but it only returns one value, never an array of values. So, if you try to press `AND` into service in the condition of an `IF` in an array formula, it will not return the array of T/F values you were probably looking for, but rather a single T/F. Same goes for `OR`.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this for shorter:

```
=COUNTIF(F2:I2,TRUE)=4
```

This counts the number of `TRUE` and checks if there are 4.

Or if you don't want to 'count' them and put the number...

```
=COUNTIF(F2:I2,TRUE)=COUNTA(F2:I2)
```

The above will not take into consideration blank cells. If you want to count them too:

```
=COUNTIF(F2:I2,TRUE)=COUNTA(F2:I2)+COUNTBLANK(F2:I2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the fact that TRUE evaluates to 1 and FALSE evaluates to 0 in certain circumstances.

[Description of TRUE and FALSE evaluation](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/oddity/C39)

Using the link above you could use the function

```
=product(F2:I2*1)
```

which would evaluate to 1 if they are all true and 0 if there are any falses or blanks.

this function need to be entered by pressing **ctrl+shift+enter** as it's an array formula.

Comment: But if there are `1` and `TRUE` within the data, that formula will count the `1` as `TRUE` as well, which I don't think is intended. But well, if OP's range can contain only boolean, there's no way this can go wrong.